# What is the significance of Bellman-Ford and linear programming for scheduling and makespans?

Tags: optimization, shortest-path, linear-programming, weighted-graphs, scheduling

CLRS exercise 24.4-9 says the following:

> Show that the Bellman-Ford algorithm, when run on the constraint graph for a system $Ax \leq b$ of difference constraints, minimizes the quantity $\max_i\{x_i\} - \min_i\{x_i\}$ subject to $Ax \leq b$. Explain how this fact might come in handy if the algorithm is used to schedule construction jobs.

I understand how to prove the result, but I'm having trouble imagining how to map these $x_i$ to quantities in scheduling, like "job begin time", "job end time", "job duration", "cost", etc. I've seen several places claim that this can be used to minimize "makespan", i.e. total duration of a schedule of jobs, but I don't see the connection.

In Chapter 24 of the book, constraints $x_k - x_j \leq b$, with $j,k\geq 1$ are converted into vertices $(v_j, v_k)$ with weight $b$. A source vertex $v_0$ is added, with zero-weight edges going to all $v_1, v_2 \ldots v_n$, so Bellman-Ford gives the solution $x_i = \delta(v_0, v_i)$, that is, the most negative path from $v_0$ to $v_i$.

Superficially, it sounds right to just say "$x_i$ are the completion times, so if you minimize the difference between the earliest and the latest, that minimizes the total or cost you spend working".

However, if $x_i$ is "the completion time for job $i$ or something like that, what would be the significance of a constraint like $x_i - x_j \leq b$? "Job $i$ must be finished at at most $b$ hours after job $j$"? That sounds somewhat contrived and unrealistic. What's a more natural mapping of these $x_i$ to scheduling concepts?

Comment: What exactly is the scheduling problem involved? What sort of constraints do we have?

Comment: Intuitively, you don't have to choose between "finish time" and "start time" in your variables. Suppose our variables are $s_1,...,s_n$ and $f_1,...,f_n$ then if we add the constraints $f_i\ge s_i$ for all $i$, the target function becomes $\max_i f_i-\max_i s_i$ which is the makespan. Now activity $i$ is of duration $t_i$ and activity $i$ ends before activity $j$ starts are obviously difference constraints.

Comment: @Ariel I don't know what the constraints are; that's actually my question. The exercise seems to be asking us to *come up* with constraints that would make sense in the context of "scheduling construction jobs", but other than that, tells us nothing. If you want "activity $i$ is of duration $t_i$, wouldn't the constraint be $s_i - f_i \leq -t_i$?

Comment: Yes, If you insist on positive $b$ for some reason then you need something different